# What is the cardinality of the set of possible wavefunctions $\Psi: (\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, cardinals, infinity, quantum-field-theory

In QFT (quantum field theory), a wave-function $\Psi$ takes in a scalar field ($\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$) as input, and returns a complex number ($\mathbb{C}$) as output. Thus:

$$\Psi: (\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$$

According to the [Beth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number) article on Wikipedia, the set all functions $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a cardinality of $2^{\mathfrak{c}} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$$

I want to know the number of wave-functions $\Psi$ possible; that is, the cardinality of the set of all wave functions $\Psi$.

Comment: As notation: The set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted by $B^A$. So the domain of $\Psi$ can be better written as $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R^3}$.

Comment: Note that since $\Bbb R^3$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ all have the same cardinality, the question is reduced to calculating the cardinality of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}}$. The order of exponentiation is as usual.

Comment: Are wave functions assumed to be continuous?

Comment: It is the same as $2^{2^{\mathfrak{c}}}$ — this is straightforwardly proved in the same way as one can show that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ — but you're not going to be able to characterize it explicitly beyond that.

Comment: Yes! According to Wikipedia, wave-functions "must be must be everywhere continuous and everywhere continuously differentiable."

Comment: @AnujManojShah That's going to affect things quite a bit; it likely drops the cardinality down all the way to $\mathfrak{c}$. On the other hand, I suspect Wikipedia is talking about wave _functions_, which are just maps $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C}$, not the entities in QFT.

Comment: Thank you Aryaman Maithani, Jason DeVito, and Seven Stadnicki! So, the answer is somewhere between $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ on the lower end, and $2^{2^{\mathfrak{c}}} = 2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}$ on the higher end.